# Dynamic segments for nested ember routes not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a nested route structure:

```
 //router.js

  this.route('maps', { path: '/maps' }, function () {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:id' }, function () {
      this.route('display', { path: '/display' }),
      this.route('layers', function () {
        this.route('create')
      })
    });
  });
```

my understanding here is that I should have a route `maps.show.display` that should take a single dynamic segment like `maps/1/display`

However when I go to transition or link to this ie:

```
//maps route

afterModel: function (resolvedModel) {
 var newestFlight = resolvedModel.content[0];
 var newestMap = newestFlight.get('map');
 this.transitionTo('maps.show.display', newestMap);
}
```

or

```
{{#link-to 'maps.show.display' id}}show map{{/link-to}}
```

I get an error:

```
 Error while processing route: maps.index More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: maps.show.index
```

It makes it even weirder that this route accepted the same dynamic segment when it was just `maps/display` so I don't understand why nesting it further breaks it.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

edit: interestingly, [this awesome tool](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/)

also seems to agree that I should have a dynamic segment here if you post my route in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rofowuneni/1/edit?html,css,js,output

BTW I think this:

```
this.route('display', { path: '/display' });
this.route('layers', function () {
  this.route('create')
});
```

Is supposed to be (not that it matters):

```
this.route('display', { path: '/display' });
this.route('layers', function () {
  this.route('create');
});
```

What's your ember version?

Comment: currently running 1.13.0

could it be where I am calling it or should that not matter? could it be that in the mapsRoute i have an incorrect context or something?

if it makes a difference I hit this while trying to move to a pod structure

Comment: @Andrew What happens if you visit the target URL directly?

Comment: uhhh ... lets forget this ever happened. I had an invalid route definition hidden at the bottom of my router.js which was overriding the routes displayed above with nonsense. Thank you SO MUCH though. your last comment helped me figure it out. Up to you but if you want to add this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: is there any difference besides the semi-colon?

Comment: Not that I can think of. I just thought that maybe your Route was broken and not the linking possibly. Glad you figured it out. :)